# Text box value doesn't get post after selecting a date from Jquery datepicker

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I create a textbox and add a Jquery UI datepicker.But when I select and click the button.the textbox doesnt get post and show an error message like(Notice: Undefined index: date_text in C:....................\file.php on line 57 ).But when I enter a date using keyboard without having a datepicker it will submit well.Please help me.How can I do this having datepicker

this is my jquery code

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );

    });
    </script>
```

this is my textfield

```
<div id="datetobe">Date to be dispose
               <label for="date_to_dispose"> <input name="datepicker" type="text" id="datepicker"   class="textfield" /></label>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the callback function for the datepicker.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Events tab, onSelect event. RTM.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'whatever',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { ... }
});
```

Comment: What is dateText and inst parameter? what i include inside curly brases in that on select function?

Comment: Wouldn't the onClose event be more appropriate? The submit shouldn't happen until they finish picking the date, not when they first select the datepicker (unless you're using an inline datepicker).

Comment: Read the documentation. "The function receives the selected date as text and the datepicker instance as parameters." Inside the curly braces you should do something like $("#myform").submit().

Comment: Seriously, @LahiruChathuranga, read the documentation. I provided a link.

Comment: I dont want to post the form when i select the date. Posting is done by a button. When I select the date it will display in texbox.but when I click the save button  an error message is comming like undefined index

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: date_text in C:\....................\file.php on line 57

Comment: @LahiruChathuranga <input name="datepicker" /> will post to $_POST['datepicker'] not $_POST['date_text']

Comment: try this before you access $_POST:  echo "<pre>"; var_dump($_POST); echo "</pre>";

Comment: Now it works fine...thanks bro your help..cheers !! if you like add me on facebook (https://www.facebook.com/LCBCentral)